# how to pass div value to window.open?

Tags: javascript, popup

I'm trying to pass a `DIV` to a new window.

#### JavaScript

```
function openWin() {
    myWindow=window.open('','','width=200,height=100');
}
```

#### HTML

```
<div id="pass">pass this to the new window</div>
<a href="#" onclick="openWin();">click</a>
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: The div has no "value" property. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
var divText = document.getElementById("pass").outerHTML;
var myWindow = window.open('','','width=200,height=100');
var doc = myWindow.document;
doc.open();
doc.write(divText);
doc.close();
```

([Demo at jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/KZYJU/))

Answer (score 1):

it worked for me

```
var divText = document.getElementById("id").outerHTML;
    var myWindow = window.open('','','width=200,height=100');
    var doc = myWindow.document;
    doc.open();
    doc.write(divText);
    doc.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the id of the div to the function.

```
 function openWin(id) {
     var divText = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
     myWindow=window.open('','','width=200,height=100');
 }



 <div id="pass">pass this to the new window</div>
 <a href="#" onclick="openWin('pass')" />click</a>
```

Comment: You haven't used 'divText' while opening new window. How this is supposed to work?