# Take a <div> from one HTML page and display in pop-up on another page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to take just one div from one HTML page and display it in a popup on another page.

I only want one div and its contents, and not the rest of the HTML from that page pulled into the popup so iframe is not suitable.

PAGE-1.HTM:

```
<body>
<div class="one">content</div>
<div class="two">content</div>
<div class="three">content</div>
<body>
```

PAGE-2.HTM:

```
<a href="">Get Div Two</a>
```

So, when I click 'get div two' link in page-2.htm is gets **only** div.two from page-1.htm and displays it in a popup on page-2.htm

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments

Comment: thanks for this. it works well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @pawel's suggestion of [api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments](https://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments)

I did this:

```
$( ".popup" ).load( "page-1.htm .two" );
```

To populate div.popup on page-2.htm, then show .popup on clicking 'Get Div Two'

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```js
$("a").on("click", function() {
  $.get('/PAGE-1.HTM').then(function(responseData) {
    var $responseData = $(responseData.html);
    var div = $responseData.find('.two').html();
    if (div.length > 0) {
      $('.your-popup').append(div);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Please see updated answer, and tell me what do you want next.

Comment: Thanks, this works, but using pawel's suggestion above is much less code (see below)

Answer (score 0):

use this javascript here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kikuyu1/cwu9kfvt/) 
this question is well demostrated here [how to pass div value to window.open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12311268/how-to-pass-div-value-to-window-open)

```html
function openWin() {
    var divText = document.getElementById("window").outerHTML;
    var myWindow = window.open('', '', 'width=200,height=100');
    var doc = myWindow.document;
    doc.open();
    doc.write(divText);
    doc.close();
}
```